# Random loop function - jsonp

Tags: javascript, json, loops, random

I'm trying to randomize a standard loop function. Here's the original loop :

```
success: function(data) {
for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  $("#myimages").append("<a href='" + data.data[i].link + "' target='_blank' style='float:center;width:300px; height:300px;'><img style='width:20%;' src='" + data.data[i].images.standard_resolution.url + "' /></a>");
  }
}
```

Could anyone help me out. I've had no luck so far.

Comment: what about it do you want to be random?

Comment: the #myimages container will load images, I'd like it to hit 15 but randomize them

Comment: Rearrange `data` in random order, then use your `for` loop as-is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a fiddle showing 15 numbers being randomized and then looped through: http://jsfiddle.net/pH6Lx/ .

```
function Shuffle(o) {
for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
return o;
};

$(document).ready(function() {
//init array
var testArray = [];

//Fill it with 15 numbers    
for(var i=0;i<15;i++)
    testArray.push(i);

//Shuffle it ("randomize")    
Shuffle(testArray);

//Do something with these numbers    
 for (var i=0;i<testArray.length;i++) {
     $('#random').append(testArray[i]+'<br />');
   }
});
```

In your case this might all happen inside your callback instead.

Comment: I noticed there's a jsonp call, would this affect the script?

Comment: You should be able to replace my document.ready with your success: function(data) event, and then put your .append where mine is. In the end it's just a loop, except here the values between 0 and 15 are randonmized. Without your full script, it's impossible to test if it will all work together.

Comment: Torrobinson, they've pointed me out to the source, it's a Codepen http://codepen.io/projectaaron/pen/Foyhp

Comment: Does this do the trick? http://cdpn.io/tlCho

Comment: It does, thanks a bunch Torrobinson! You rocked my day!!!

Answer (score 0):

First, just randomize the array, see:  [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-a-javascript-array).

```
success: function(data) {
    function shuffleArray(array) {
        for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            var temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = temp;
        }
        return array;
    }

    shuffleArray(data);
```

Then proceed as before:

```
    for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        $("#myimages").append("<a href='" + data.data[i].link + "' target='_blank' style='float:center;width:300px; height:300px;'><img style='width:20%;' src='" + data.data[i].images.standard_resolution.url + "' /></a>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Same here Lyn, the images won't load anymore. I noticed its using jsonp. Might be my issue?

Comment: You must have a bug in some other part of your code then.

Comment: Still looking and trying... thx Lyn

Comment: Lyn, I just got word on the source. Please have a quick look here. http://codepen.io/projectaaron/pen/Foyhp

Answer (score 0):

if you are passing a list of images in data.data is possible to do as below

```
 success: function(data) {

    var numberOfImages = Math.min( 15, data.data.length ) ; //bug free to don't repeat        
    var alreadyShow = {}; //to don't repeat


    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfImages ; i++) {

        do{

            var imgIndex = Math.round( Math.random() * ( data.data.length - 1 ) );    

        }while( alreadyShow[imgIndex] );

        alreadyShow[imgIndex] = true;    

        $("#myimages").append("<a href='" + data.data[imgIndex].link + "' target='_blank' style='float:center;width:300px; height:300px;'><img style='width:20%;' src='" + data.data[imgIndex].images.standard_resolution.url + "' /></a>");
      }
    }
```

it's randomize without repeat

Comment: I gave this a try Luan, no images are loading unfortunately

Comment: Got word from were this comes from http://codepen.io/projectaaron/pen/Foyhp Any idea how we could randomize this Luan?